# Get relative paths of folder and its files with length in mb separate column?

Tags: powershell

I need to find relative paths of folders and its files with length in MB in separate csv columns and compare that csv file with another csv file and print unmatched filepaths with length in another csv in absolute path

```
$srcpth = "C:\Users\vavenkatamanoj\Downloads"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpth -File -Recurse

foreach ($f in $files)
{
    $filen = $f.Name
    $relativePath = $f.fullname.remove(0,($srcpth.length))
    $filesize = $f.Length
    Write-Output "$relativePath,$filesize" | Out-File C:\Users\vavenkatamanoj\Downloads\check.csv -Append
}
```

I try this script to get relative paths with size. It is ok but filepath and length are returned in the same column; I need separate columns. Can anyone help me?

Comment: To get the relative path, you can either use [Resolve-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) with the `-Relative` switch, or use .Net [Path.GetRelativePath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath). Also, create **objects** with the wanted properties and use [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to create your csv instead of fabricating the rows yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
$srcpth = "C:\Users\vavenkatamanoj\Downloads" 
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpth -File -Recurse 
$result = foreach ($f in $files) {

[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        fileName = $f.Name
        RelativePath  =  $f.fullname.remove(0,($srcpth.length))
        FileSize = $f.Length
    }



}
$result | Export-Csv "c:\temp\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Use PSCustomObject for creating structured data. Please find the link below for more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Like this we have 2csv files . Now I need to compare that 2 csv files and find the unmatched file paths and print in absolute path.

Comment: As a quick note, and not to nit-pick, `PSCustomObject`'s are *ordered* by default.

Comment: @Rajesh - In your question you have asked for results in two columns. Please try with compare-object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment,

Why not create a CSV file that has both the Length, the Absolute and the Relative path all in-one?

```
$srcpth = 'C:\Users\vavenkatamanoj\Downloads'

# needed for Resolve-Path -Relative
$currentPath = (Get-Location).Path
Set-Location $srcpth
# you could now remove the -Path $srcpth if you like
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpth -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # output Objects
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        FileName     = $_.Name
        FileSize     = $_.Length
        RelativePath = $_.FullName | Resolve-Path -Relative
        AbsolutePath = $_.FullName
    }
}

# now, output the data as CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\vavenkatamanoj\Downloads\check.csv' -NoTypeInformation
# restore the current location
Set-Location $currentPath
```

Comment: no no . i have 2 csv files with relativepath and length .now i need to compare that both csv files and output is unmatched filepaths present in both csv in absolute path length in mb

Comment: @Rajesh Sorry, but now I have no idea what it is you want.. Compare the files listed in two csv files and check if their lengths differ? I guess you need to show us those csv files and explain better with what you want as output. An example  would be helpful

Comment: by using your snippet  i generate 2 csv files from 2 different folders. now i need to compare that csv files and print only unmatched file paths with length (separate coloumns)